# Elasticsearch - Python client - How to match on multiple fields?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm trying to match on more than one field when querying an ES server via the Python API. But can't figure out the syntax within Python:

I've tried;

```
res = es.search(index="pyats", doc_type="router_show", body={"query": {"match": {"name": "mark"} AND {"age": "21"}}}, size=1000)
```

and

```
res = es.search(index="pyats", doc_type="router_show", body={"query": {"match_all": {"name": "mark"} AND {"age": "21"}}}, size=1000)
```

and

```
res = es.search(index="pyats", doc_type="router_show", body={"query": {"match": {"name": "mark"}}, {"match": {"age": "21"}}}, size=1000)
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.
None, seem to be working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure that age field is of the type integer or string. The keyword which will solve your problem is `must`.

```
{
    "query": {
        "constant_score" : {
            "filter" : {
                 "bool" : {
                    "must" : [
                        { "term" : { "age" : 21 } }, 
                        { "term" : { "name" : "mark" } } 
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```